# display output from stored values in python program

Tags: python

I'm a new learner in python. please help me for this program

```
name = ['a','b','c']
phone = [1,2,3]
```

I want in output that, when I type name 'a', phone number '1' would display and so on. If in output don't find any name stored in list then display `not found`.

Please help me how to write this program !!

Comment: Sure you will get help but you will have to share your effort first. Please include what have you tried so far.

Comment: why have you tagged java here ? your q. is only about python

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
name = ['a','b','c']
phone = [1,2,3]
in_name = input("Enter a name: ") #gets the name
try:
    print(phone[name.index(input)]) # prints the phone number with same index as name
except:
    print("Value not found") # If there is no index(input) print value not found
```

However, I would not recommend doing this. Instead, use a dictionary:

```
phoneBook = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

It is much easier to work with.